# Transferring array data into a PHP script obtained via the SOAP protocol and transferring it to a Java script

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to coding.
I receive data using the soap protocol, I receive a PHP array

```
    <?php   
    $geostation = array ();
    foreach ($res->TripPointArr as $point) {
    $geostation[] = array(
    'stationName' =>$point->StationNm,
    'longitude' => $point->StLONGITUDE,
    'latitude' => $point->StLATITUDE,
    'timearrft' => $point->DtTmArrivalFt
    );
    }`
    $jsondata = json_encode($geostation);
    echo $jsondata;
```

```
        fetch('getdata.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        })
       .catch(error => console.error('Ошибка при получении данных:', error));
```

I get an error SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 5795
when I try to convert the entire array to json.
But if I exclude the elements 'timesendft' 'timearrft' from the array, the names and coordinates remain, then the json is valid, and if I remove the coordinates and leave the names and date and time, then everything is fine too. But if you try the entire array, then json gives an error.

Comment: Unless it's a posted typo, what's with the backtick after the closing `}` to the `foreach`?

Comment: Make sure your php script doesn't echo or output any other content after it echoes the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was encoding. I figured it out myself

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$jsondata = json_encode($geostation);
echo $jsondata;
```

Heаder had to be prescribed earlier than json_encode.